# Numbering equations with more than one counter

Tags: numbering

I am recently texing my lecture notes in maths and want to include a subsection with the exercises. The numbering of the lecture notes is (sec.eq), but for the exercises, I want the numbering to be (sec.ex.eq). I don't know how to achieve this.

(06.09.2017) Thank you for the comments so far. To give a minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{Exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
Here is section 1.
\subsection{ssec1.1}
Here I have a subsection.
\subsection{ssec1.2}
Here I have another subsection.
\subsection{exercises1}
Here I have the exercises (using the above defined theroem enviroment).

\section{sec2}
Here the same.
\subsection{ssec2.1}
Here the same.
\subsection{ssec2.2}
Here the same.
\subsection{exercises2}
And again exercises.
\end{document}
```

The numbering is about the equation numbers, there I have my problems.

Comment: This depends on the way how the `exercises` are counted/numbered. If there is an `exercises` counter, I would guess `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{exercise}.\arabic{equation}}` before using the first `exercise` environment and `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}`. Best use `chngcntr` package. Please provide a minimal compiling document.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: If you provide your tags as MWE, it will help to analyze the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `\theequation` can be changed locally in the `Exercise` environment which is defined by `\newtheorem` with

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{Exercise}{%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theExercise.\arabic{equation}}
}
```

Since this occurs within the environment group, the redefinition is not affecting `\theequation` used in `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Since `Exercise` is defined to be counted within `section`, `\theExercise` is already using `\thesection.\arabic{Exercise}` by design.

Please note that the equation counter is not reset here with each `Exercise` however!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{Exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\AtBeginEnvironment{Exercise}{%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theExercise.\arabic{equation}}
}



\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
Here is section 1.

% Regular equation environment, using a different counter. 

\begin{equation}
  E = mc^{2}
\end{equation}
\subsection{ssec1.1}
Here I have a subsection.
\subsection{ssec1.2}
Here I have another subsection.
\subsection{exercises1}
Here I have the exercises (using the above defined theroem enviroment).

\begin{Exercise}
  \begin{equation}
    E = mc^{2}
    \end{equation}

And other equations:

\begin{align}
  E^{2} &= (p c)^{2} + (m_{0} c^{2})^{2} \\
  c^{2} &= a^{2} + b^{2} 
\end{align}

\end{Exercise}




\section{sec2}
Here the same.
\subsection{ssec2.1}
Here the same.
\subsection{ssec2.2}
Here the same.
\subsection{exercises2}
And again exercises.

\begin{Exercise}
  \begin{equation}
    E = mc^{2}
    \end{equation}

And other equations:

\begin{align}
  E^{2} &= (p c)^{2} + (m_{0} c^{2})^{2} \\
  c^{2} &= a^{2} + b^{2} 
\end{align}

\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest the usage of `\counterwithin{equation}{Exercise}` within `\AtBeginEnvironment{Exercise}{}` in order to reset the equation counter with each `Exercise`...

Comment: Thank you @Christian Hupfer. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @DarkViole7: Please accept my solution then in order to mark it as solved